# "The constructor Geocoder(Context, Locale) is undefined"?

Tags: android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am making an android app, and need to use Google maps' reverse geocoding. The relevant code is:

```
  Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
  List<Address> matches = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
  // latitude and longitude are double variables containing the coordinates.
```

On the first line of the code above I am getting the compiling error:

`"The constructor Geocoder(Context, Locale) is undefined"`

I tried googling but could not find a resolution. Thanks.

Comment: check that your import is   android.location.Geocoder

Comment: @blackbelt Yep, that worked. Write as answer for points.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue:: Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault()); ............... was giving a similar error but Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MyActivity.this, Locale.getDefault()); ...... resolved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor `Geocoder(Context, Locale)` is defined. Check if you import the correct class

```
 android.location.Geocoder
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#Geocoder%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.Locale%29) the documentation